# dynamically created button wont trigger function

Tags: python, html, jquery, django

I have a drop down list to which I append buttons by js. Everything works fine but I couldn't get my buttons to perform their onclick action.

here is the code which generates the buttons:

```
      function (data) {
                        $("#pop-up").css("display", "none");
                        $("#pop-up").empty();
                        $("#pop-up").append("<p class=search-top>titles</p>");

                        if (data.title4) {
                            $("#pop-up").append("<b onmousedown='event.preventDefault()' onclick='showtime('pop-button4')' id=pop-button4>"+data.title4+"</b>")
                        }
                        if (data.title3) {
                            $("#pop-up").append("<b onmousedown='event.preventDefault()' onclick='showtime('pop-button3')' id=pop-button3>"+data.title3+"</b>")
                        }
                        if (data.title2) {
                            $("#pop-up").append("<b onmousedown='event.preventDefault()' onclick='showtime('pop-button2')' id=pop-button2>"+data.title2+"</b>")
                        }
                        if (data.title1) {
                            $("#pop-up").css("display", "block");
                            $("#pop-up").append("<b onmousedown='event.preventDefault()' id=pop-button1>"+data.title1+"</b>")}
```

I tryed both js and jquery but couldn't get them to work, the last function I tryed is:

```
 $('#pop-button1').on('click', function(){
        console.log("here")
    });
```

It does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your callback to be:

```
$(document).on('click', '#pop-button1', function(){ 
    console.log("here");
});
```

By doing that you might achieve what you're looking for.